# How to find redundant lines on a plane?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, geometry

Consider an object "living" in a 2D space and currently located at **(0;0)**.

Object is surrounded by two main restricting lines **x=0** and **y=0**, also by a bunch of additional lines **A*x+B*y=C** (triplets **A,B,C** are contained within some **N-by-3** array.)

Is there a straightforward algorithm for removing redundant lines? I have my data in MatLab and it has a bunch of fancy native functions but I am still not quite sure where to start.

---

For example, below all lines **A*x+B*y=C** are shown in blue, redundant lines are marked in red.

[image: Link to image].

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the criteria of redundancy? Also, the image is not very clear, which red lines, those edited or the solid ones or both?

Comment: do you mean the lines that create the minimum enclosing area? like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BjYU7.png

Comment: @OlegKomarov Sorry about the confusion. I meant only edited red lines are redundant (solid curves are not related to my question, since I'm color-blind I didn't see they're red). Line is NOT-redundant if at least one of its points can be connected to **(0;0)** without crossing other defined lines. Otherwise it is redundant.

Comment: @Amro Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to say.

Comment: This is the intersection of halfspaces problem in two dimensions, which can be solved in O(n log n) time using polar duality and a convex hull routine, which MATLAB appears to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment: for each non-main line Ax + By = C, let A' = A/C and B' = B/C so that the line equation can be written A'x + B'y = 1. (C = 0 necessitates a special case that I'll ignore.)

Now compute the 2D convex hull of the pairs (A', B'). MATLAB has [`convhull`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) for this; set `simplify` to true. Retain those lines corresponding to points in the upper-right quarter of the hull. (Going counterclockwise, the first point in this quarter is the rightmost, choosing the topmost in case of a tie. The last is the topmost, choosing the rightmost in case of a tie.)

Comment: Could you please kindly explain the retaining process again for a particular example? (A', B') components are represented by [0.2759   -0.1333    0.2960   -0.3956] and [0.0690    0.5333    0.1245    0.9735]. convhull(A, B,'simplify', true) gives [1     3     4     2     1].

Comment: @Pranasas Rightmost is 3. Topmost is 4. Take everything from 3 to 4 (just 3 and 4 in this case). If r&t were 3&2, then take from 3 to 2 (3,4,2). If r&t were 2&3, then take from 2 to the end, then the beginning to 3 (2,1,3).

Answer (score 2):

Do you need simplicity or efficency?

The most straightforward algorithm would simply construct the object, side after side. At each step you have a point p and direction v (a vector); assuming you construct the object clockwise you start with p = (0, 0) and direction v = (0, 1). At each step you sort all lines by comparing values q such that p + q * v is the point where the line crosses the line of v (you ignore parallel lines). The complexity is O(n^2 log n).

Comment: How to choose the next direction when I know the current direction and the "closest" line? I am not really experienced in programming.

Comment: The next point is where current and next line cross. The next direction is the direction of the next line. If the next line is C = Ax + By, then the vector is (1, s * A/B) if B != 0, (0, s * 1) otherwise. s is 1 or -1, and you will have to choose it so that you make a clockwise turn. To see if you turn right or left, check the sign of cross product of old and new direction.

Comment: "...the vector is (1, s * A/B) if B != 0, (0, s * 1) otherwise..." if the first component is never negative, then I'm effectively never going left.

Comment: One example of it not working would be the last step before closing the loop. That is let's say I hit the next point **(0;5)** and the next line **y=0**. I'd need the next direction to be something like **(-1;0)** to close the loop...

Comment: once you hit the X axis you just stop